# Algorithm for finding shortest directed odd cycle in a digraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to find an algorithm to find the shortest directed odd cycle in a digraph. My intuition is to approach this using breadth-first-search. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(V, E)$ be a graph. Create a new graph bipartite graph $G'$ with $V_1$ and $V_2$ the vertices of each part. We identify each vertex of $V$ with a vertex in $V_1$, and same for $V_2$ (so |V| = |V_1| = |V_2|). For each arc in $G$, we add one arc in $G'$ going from $V_1$ to $V_2$ and one from $V_2$ to $V_1$, with the same extremities as the one in $G$. Now, an odd circuit (you are allowed to pass through a vertex multiple times) passing through $u$ in $G$ is equivalent to a path in $G'$ from the vertex $u$ of $V_1$ to the vertex $u$ of $V_2$. So you can find the shortest odd circuit in $V$ by finding the shortest odd circuit passing through $u$ for each $u\in V$ in $\mathcal{O}(|E||V|)$.

It is easy to see that the shortest odd circuit is also an odd cycle, because each circuit passing through a vertex twice can be decomposed in two shorter circuits, one of which needs to be odd.

I don't know if there exist an algorithm achieving a better bounds than this. Also, it is worth noticing that the problem is much harder if we search for a shortest even cycle, and [it was shown to be tractable only very recently.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.02992)